# How to search through different parts of a graph?

Tags: algorithm, search, matrix, graph

Recently I met a coding problem that asks you on a given graph to find out how many different "closed" sub-graphs there are. And after you have found that out you need to search each sub-graph and find how many element are there in each sub-graph. So now to define sub-graph. Let's say we're given

```
.#####.
#.....#
#.E##.#
#.#.#.#
#.#####
#E..#E#
.#####.
```

Think of it like a maze where dots represents moving space, while the hashtags are walls and you can move horizontally or vertically. So let's say you are at one point in the graph. All the points you can reach by moving horizontally or vertically are part of a that particular "closed" sub-graph. So for the given example we have 3 "closed" sub-graphs

```
1#####1
#11111#
#11##1#       
#1#2#1#
#1#####
#111#3#
1#####3
```

Also there are 2 elements in the first sub-graph, no elements in the second and one in the 3rd.

I guess it really doesn't matter what searching method you use, so I used BFS starting from the first entered dot in the line. So once I've reach all possible points starting from that particular point I have found one sub-graph and I have counted how many elements there are in the sub-graph. But the problem now is how to find the starting point of the next sub-graph. I can not think of another way than iterating through the graph until you find a non-visited point and the apply the BFS repeateadly until you have visited all the points. But this method proves to be too much time-consuming, so is there any way I can efficiently find the sub-graphs? For example is there a way to stack at least a point from each sub-graph in a queue, while you're entering the line?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating through the entire graph to find non-visited points you could try iterating though just the walls adjacent to your known sub-groups and look for non-visited points adjacent to those walls. You would be able to compile the list of walls during the bfs.

Comment: Consider this case, let all the whole graph be filled with hashtags, except for the first and the last entrance. So basically it comes down to searching the whole graph. I know that it would run faster than to iterate through the whole graph, but in some marginal cases will give a big time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can first iterate the graph and find all possible "starting point", hold these elements in a [set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28abstract_data_type%29) data structure, and when you do a BFS - for each point you find - remove it from the set of entry points.

Now, at each iteration - all you have to do is choose a random entry point from the set (which is guaranteed to be unvisited yet), and do a new BFS.

Comment: Since all dats are "starting points" that would mean a lot of elements in the set. And I guess I would need O(N) time to search the set just to remove the point from it, since it's visited. And since there are N dots I would need to iteratte through it N times, which means O(N^2) complexity just to remove the points.

Comment: @Stefan4024 No, removing an element from a set is O(1) if the set is hash based and O(logn) if it's tree based.